# Problem with sleep on mac osx snow leopard - when i do ctrl+cmd+eject to sleep, it wakes up 20 secs later

Tags: macos, mac, osx-snow-leopard, sleep

I'm having a problem with putting my snow leopard imac to sleep - when i do ctrl+cmd+eject (or whatever the shortcut is to put it to sleep) it goes sleep, it wakes up 20 secs later.

After it wakes up, i do the shortcut to put it to sleep again and it stays down.

It's been doing this for the last month or so. I'm suspecting it may be skype - i've started using that lately (although it may not be, too).

Any suggestions?
Thanks

-edit-

One thing i noticed this morning, is that when it woke itself up, it flashed a message on the screen saying the mouse had been disconnnected (i have a magic mouse). The battery is newly replaced in the mouse however.

Comment: Do you have peripherals connected? A magic trackpad under a shifting stack of paper? Or do you maybe use FaceTime on your Mac?

Comment: Only have the mouse and keyboard, no other peripherals.

Comment: It is not unusual for a Bluetooth mouse to disable while the computer is asleep. You will then see the "Disconnected" when the computer wakes, and then you have to wiggle the mouse to wake it and it will be "Connected". I made an edit to my answer to remove this as a factor.

Comment: Might be worth a try disabling wake for network access: http://superuser.com/questions/179131/mac-os-x-unexpected-wake-up-after-hibernate

Comment: I tried disabling wake for network access, that didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Reboot, and try putting it to sleep at the login screen. If that works, try going to sleep again immediately after you login. If that doesn't work, check the Login Items for your Account in System Preferences. After that, it would be something you've run.

You can run /Applications/Utilities/Console and search All Messages for "wake" and "sleep"

**Edit:** to remove Bluetooth as a factor, open Bluetooth in System Preferences, open the Advanced sheet, and uncheck "Allow Bluetooth devices to wake this computer".

Comment: I'll definitely try those suggestions.

Comment: In the console, how do i search the messages as you suggest?

Comment: Not "the console", but the Console app. I made an edit, but the simple way to find it is to use Spotlight. Search is in the top-right, as usual.

Comment: Well, there's nothing in the console. I guess i'll kill my apps one at a time until it goes away.

Comment: If i uncheck that setting, would that mean my (wireless) keyboard would then lose the ability to wake the computer?

Comment: Yes, I think so (I only have a wired keyboard). You'd then have to press the power button to wake? But as a diagnostic step, worth a shot. In fact, maybe you can borrow a wired keyboard/mouse and turn off all Bluetooth before sleeping; see if that makes a difference.